# How can I use the same Activity for different content in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-linearlayout

Consider I am using the linear layout for my app

```
 <TextView
    android:text="product 1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="54sp"
    android:background="#009611" />

<TextView
    android:text="product 2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="54sp"
    android:background="#123431" />

<TextView
    android:text="product 3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="54sp"
    android:background="#009688" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My output is:

[image: akash preet sample output]

when I select **product1** it should open **product1_des** Activity
when I select **product2** it should open **product2_des** Activity
when I select **product3** it should open **product3_des** Activity
and goes on..

And I have 1000 product should I create 1000 Activity?
How can I use the **product_des** Activity (i.e single Activity) to support all my 1000 product with different description that is related to that product?
Please help me.

Comment: You should pass your description string using bundle and then use the same activity named product_des to fetch it and place it.

Comment: yes,, you have to do that if activity name are different

Comment: No you dont need to creat so many activities,,,,you can create a single fragment that show different data when you select different options

Comment: If you think my answer is helpful mark it as a correct and upvote :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> And I have 1000 product should I create 1000 Activity? How can I use the product_des Activity (i.e single Activity) to support all my 1000 product with different description that is related to that product? Please help me.

NO!!!

You can create an `Activity` called for example `ProductDetail` but only one, and then everywhere you want to show a product detail you can use [`putExtras()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle))

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProductDetail.class);
intent.putExtra("productName", ProductName);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in `ProductDetail` you can get the name of the product with a [`Bundle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html?hl=es)

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b = getIntent().getExtras();
String name = b.getString("productName");
```